# Less optimize code

Tags: css, less

I have following structure:

```
<div class ="shops">
  <div class = "shops__item_left">
  <div class = "shops__item_right">
  <div class = "shops__descr">
</div>
```

And lets say I need all blocks starting with 'shops_item' have one common css property like `background: black`.

How do I do this?
Of course I can do it like this:

```
   .shops {
     font-size: 15px;
     &__item_left { 
       background: black;
     }
     &__item_right { 
       background: black;
     }
```

But how do I get rid of this repetition.

Answer (score 0):

A few options. You might want to refactor a bit like so (note the multiple classnames):

```html
<div class="shops">
  <div class="shops__item shops__item--left">
  <div class="shops__item shops__item--right">
  <div class="shops__descr">
</div>
```

```css
.shops {
  font-size: 15px;

  &__item { 
     background: black;

     &--left { ... }
     &--right { ... }
  }

}
```

Alternatively you could leave your markup the same and select all elements with classnames *containing* `shops__item` somewhere in them.

```css
[class*="shops__item"] {
  background: black;
}
```